# dojo's onkeypress event, deprecated?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo's *behavior* functionality to add events. I'm checking a text field to see what's being entered. As far I understand, the documentation suggests me to use `onkeypress` over `onkeydown`.

*Part of object*

```
'#myTextField' : {

onkeypress: function(event)
    {
        console.log(event.charCode);                
    }
}
```

It works fine, but in both (latest) Chrome and Firefox I get warning messages in the console.

**Chrome** says *event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.*

**Firefox** says that `getAttributeNodeNS()`is deprecated.

I haven't tried any other browsers.

Is there a better(newer) way to do it, or what is this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `keypress`/`keydown` events that are deprecated.

Apparently dojo tries to copy some of event properties (`layerX`, `layerY`) that has been deprecated.
There is nothing wrong with dojo, but these messages are quite annoying, so I hope they will fix them soon.

You can read more details here http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14114

Until this is fixed you can you set event callback function in HTML element, if you're not picky of your javascript locations. This will not trigger warning messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't bother me, as long as I know that my events won't stop working all of a sudden. But it sounds like I'm safe then?

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom Yep, you are safe. The events themselves are working and won't be deprecated anytime soon